# Counting Upper and Lower characters in a string using an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have been working on this problem for two days now and have no idea where I'm going wrong.

Essentially I need to ask a user for a string of words. 
I need to set up an `int` array of 26 elements that holds the count of lower case letters and one for upper case letters.

I can't get the program to compare with the array elements properly. This is my code so far:

```
public class Lab17Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
        int lLetter = 0;
        int uLetter = 0;

        // int[] alph = new int [26];
        int alph [] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
        int Alph [] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

        System.out.println("Enter a phrase");
        String user = kb.nextLine();
        // to print out length of word
        System.out.println("Total number of letters is " + user.length());

        for(int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++)
        {


        }

        System.out.println("Upper case letters are:" + uLetter);
        System.out.println("Lower case letters are:" + lLetter);
        int otherL = user.length() - (uLetter + lLetter);

        // to print out other chars that aren't letters
        System.out.println("Number of all other letters is " + otherL );
    }
}
```

Inside my for loop is where I've been trying different if conditions. I have no idea what I'm missing?

Comment: try Character.isUpperCase() / .isLowerCase()

Comment: That does work. 

I've used this in my for loop.
 for(int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++)
   {
    if(Character.isUpperCase(userInput.charAt(i)))
    { 
     uLetter++;
    }
    else if(Character.isLowerCase(userInput.charAt(i)))
    {
     lLetter++;
    }
    
   }


but i need to use the array in some capacity.

Comment: I'm not seeing any kind of counter in there at all. Plus you have these arrays or chars `alph` and `Alph` that you don't use. Since I'm here: Don't have 2 vars with a name just different by case - it will come back and bite you...

Comment: I should have left the code in there I used for the counter, I took it out before i copied it. 

Thanks for the tip on the var names tho. Ill keep that in mind.

Comment: Do you need a count per letter or just one for all uppers and another for all lowers? If it's per letter then your commented out `alph` looks like you were closer to the right track than your current version. Just need to figure out "How can index `alph` based on an ASCII character code...."

Comment: Thanks john!

I figured the only solution was to convert the user char to ascii. I attempted that by doing the following inside my for loop. 

char character = 'a';
int ascii = (int) character;

I'm just lost beyond that point.

Comment: Are your int arrays supposed to keep a count of the number of instances of each individual letter (hence 26 entries)?

Comment: A char is pretty much already an int (just with less bits), but `a` is not value 0. Try `char character = 'a'; int index_for_a = character - 'a';`

Comment: The array is meant for comparison purposes if im understanding the question properly. I don't need to know how many times a particular letter shows up. I just need to know if a letter like D shows up in the string, I need the program to tell me if that's an upper case or lower case letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using an Array

You could use [`String.toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--) and a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) to iterate your `user`Input (you seem to have changed the variable name between your post, and your comment). Regardless, something like

```
for (char ch : user.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isLowerCase(ch)) {
        lLetter++;
    } else if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
        uLetter++;
    }
}
```

#### Using Regular Expression(s)

You could reduce your code by using a regular expression to remove all non-lowercase characters from the input and another to remove all non-uppercase characters from the input like

```
int lLetter = user.replaceAll("[^a-z]", "").length(); // <-- removes everything not a-z
int uLetter = user.replaceAll("[^A-Z]", "").length(); // <-- removes everything not A-Z
```

Comment: That worked! thank you. 

i'll run it in debug to try and find out exactly whats going on there. lol

None the less, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    int upperCount = 0;
    int lowerCount = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String w = sc.nextLine();
    for(int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++){
        if(Character.isUpperCase(w.charAt(i))){
            upperCount++;
        }else{
            lowerCount++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Upper Counts are "+upperCount+" lower counts are "+lowerCount);
```

Comment: This counts "other" characters as lower case.

Comment: if you want, you can change the else to an else if and check if it is lowercase

Comment: That works without an array.. I need to use an array as part of my solution.

Comment: what should the array do ? Do you want to put the words from the user in there ? or do you need to check each letter ? @b.Bish

Comment: I'm checking each letter once to the input from the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++)
    {
        int ch = user.charAt(i);
        if (Arrays.binarySearch(alph, ch) >= 0)
            ++lLetter;
        if (Arrays.binarySearch(Alph, ch) >= 0)
            ++uLetter;
    }
```